# Gridview combobox column hide items programmatically

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

I am trying to change the item collection programmatically in the Datagridview Combobox control.I have 3 items in Combobox which i get the datas from database;

[Item 1]

[Item 2]

[Item 3]

What i wanted to do is ;

If the combobox value is [Item 1] as a default, i can only select the [Item 2].I dont want to see the [Item 3] in the list.

Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Is it just me or this does not make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved via using CellBeginEdit event of datagrid and used cell.datasource,

```
private void dGV_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];

          if (item_type.ToString() == "item1")
            {
                try
                {
                     DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(row.Cells[3]);
                     cell.DataSource = new string[] { "Item1","Item2"};
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing the item collection programatically?
If you want only item 1 and item 2 then fetch data from the database and write 'where' condition that !=item3. You will get the data with Item 1 and Item2.

Comment: I need Item3 because if default value is item2 i can only change it to item 3..Need to change cell item collection dynamically